# How to redirect two step backward after clicking delete button in asp.net and vb.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

In my asp.net and vb.net web application I want User to go 2 steps backward (along with performing the delete action) after they click on delete button.

Currently the system redirects the user to one particular page after delete. But this causes user to click on more pages to go where they were previously because the delete action can be performed in various different locations. So I just want to redirect them where they were (i.e 2 steps backward) after clicking on delete button.

My current code is like below

```
   Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

        If Not VacancyToDelete.TotalApplications > 0 Then
            VacancyToDelete.Delete()
            Response.Redirect("/E4/Jobs/closed.aspx")

        End If

   End Sub
```

I tried the following line of code but it did not takes user back to the page. It remains on the same page and it feels like nothing has happened.

```
       Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

        If Not VacancyToDelete.TotalApplications > 0 Then
            VacancyToDelete.Delete()

        End If

         btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.back();")
   End Sub
```

Please help me with code

Thank you

If I add the following lines of code (instead of the above blocks of code )it just goes back  but not performs the delete action

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.go(-2); return false;")
 End Sub

 Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

        If Not VacancyToDelete.TotalApplications > 0 Then
            VacancyToDelete.Delete()


        End If

   End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `history.go(-2)` on your button onclick without `return false`

Comment: I have tried. But its the same result.

Comment: And you removed `Response.Redirect("/E4/Jobs/closed.aspx")` as well?

Comment: Yes I have removed that line. Please see my edited question

Comment: Try your update with `btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.go(-2);")`, i.e. with `return false;` removed.

Comment: I have tried that already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63866/discussion-between-bashabi-and-artm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform an AJAX request and then go 2 pages back in history using js [history](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp):

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-2)
}
```

Comment: I dont know ajax. can you please elaborate your code

Comment: [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/calling-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-javascript/) is a link with calling WebMethod example. Note that you'll have to pass your VacancyToDelete object id to delete it on server side.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used asp.net very much at all but it could be that you are using return false in your
onClick event.  When I run your code in a javascript debugging console like firebug I get
an illegal return statement error. Try removing the **return false;** part to see if it works. Remember that if there is no history your javascript:history.back() call will return undefined.

Comment: I have removed return false.but its the same result

Answer (score 1):

Your first code block looks right - if that's working, it's because the `if` condition isn't doing what you expect.  Set a breakpoint there and verify that the Response.Redirect line is actually executing.  As written, the delete and redirect will only happen if TotalApplications is <= 0.

Comment: In my first code block the response.redirect is working. it is in the current system. But I want to change it and redirect user to back page (i.e not into any particular page)